# What is the fastest way to update node and npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have searched online numerous times and I cannot seem to get it working. Please tell me if my understanding is incorrect:

1. **To update *npm* to the latest version:**

`npm install npm@latest -g`

2. **To update *node* to the latest version**
   Go to the official website and download it. However I would like to be able to update **node and npm** through the command line.

Anyway, running  `npm install npm@latest -g` gives me:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path D:\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Refusing to delete D:\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: D:\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

Could someone please tell me the solution of this, and also provide a way to update both **node and npm** through the command line easily?

EDIT: Sorry forgot to say, I am using windows

Comment: What is your OS? [try this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

Comment: Sorry, I have updated it. It is windows

Comment: Try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade) then

Answer (score -1):

Delete the node_modules directory completely.

Run `npm install` again.

This should help you.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but isn't node modules only for when you are working in a particular project? As in each project has a node_modules. But my problem is I simply want to update both npm an node.js

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a node modules ?

Comment: I have node module, but isn't that only inside a project?

Comment: You need to delete your node modules and run npm install. Watch your errors - one of them is about refusing to delete the node modules. do it your self

Comment: Alright I will try this, but which node_modules do I delete? There are many of them right?

Comment: All the library, go to your project folder and search for node modules folder and delete it. another option is deleting it through your VS / VSC by right clicking on it

Comment: I don't think you understand that the OP is trying to upgrade the NPM and node.js tools themselves, not some specific NPM modules.  There's no node_modules directory associated with node.js itself.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00...to be honest I was unsure if Bar understood my question or not, but I was kinda scared because I did not want to sound stupid, but at the same time I know that node_modules is the huge folder that lives in every project